# What is the normal way of getting rid of the Bearer prefix in bearer token before decoding it?

Tags: python

The client sends a bearer token to the server and it looks like so:

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

Apparently I don't need the 'Bearer' prefix so I have to get rid of it. I understand it is as simple as splitting the string and taking the right element but what I do not understand is why the library function I'm using doesn't do it for me.
I also have to check if the token is actually of the right type (which is bearer in this case). It forces me to write additional lines of code and I don't like it.

So my question is "Are there any smarter ways of processing the token?"

I'm using `PyJWT`.

Comment: PyJWT is a library to parse JSON web tokens. What library did you use to get the header?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Precisely so. As for the prefix, it's inserted in code for JWTInterceptor on the clientside.

Comment: What client side? Please do be more explicit as to what your code looks like.

Comment: JWTInterceptor is, I think, an Angular component? That's not a Python server-side framework at any rate.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The client is on Angular, but I don't think the architecture of the web application is too important here to solve that simple issue. I just need to parse the damn token, in order to do that I have to get rid of the bearer part. I don't want to do this manually. That's the issue.

Comment: Sure, but you are making a lot of assumptions that I now have to guess at.

Comment: Great question.  I noticed it was downvoted when I got to it though.  I'm disappointed in the community.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Bearer ...` string is *usually* found in a `Authorisation` header from a HTTP request. It then depends on the specific framework you are using to receive or send HTTP requests if there is specific support for such headers.

The format is not part of the JSON web token standard; the `Authorization` header, with or without `Bearer`, is a common place to find one, but a package like PyJWT only deals with the tokens, not the transport mechanism. So a library that focuses on handling JSON Web Tokens should not be expected to handle parsing tokens out of a HTTP header (though some may do).

The HTTP 1.1 specification that determines what headers on a HTTP request should look like only standardizes that a [`Authorization:` header in a request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.8) should contain *credentials*, and a [separate RFC 2617 standard on HTTP Authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) states that *credentials* should consist of at least a *scheme* and arbitrary parameters:

```
credentials = auth-scheme #auth-param
```

That's not much to go on for a Python HTTP library to work with. The specific RFC only further specifies two different authorization schemes: *Basic* and *Digest*. *Bearer* is *not part of this standard*. So a framework like Werkzeug (which underpins Flask, among others) does support parsing `Authorization` headers, but only if one of those two standardised schemes is being used (see the [`Authorization` class docs](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.Authorization)).

The `Bearer` scheme is instead part of the [OAuth 2.0 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750). It just defines that a client can send a token, one given to them, that the server can accept to authorize the request. The `Bearer` scheme is just one of several ways to send the token, and the only limitation on the token is that it should be base64-encoded. *Nothing more is said*.

But it does say that if the Authorization header is used, then the format must [follow a specific format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1):

```
 b64token    = 1*( ALPHA / DIGIT /
                   "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / "+" / "/" ) *"="
 credentials = "Bearer" 1*SP b64token
```

So `Bearer`, followed by 1 or more spaces, then followed by Base64 data with some added permitted characters (Base64 only uses letters, digits and `+` and `/` with `=` as padding at the end, so `-`, `.`, `_` and `~` are extra here). That's it.

If you must have a library, find one that handles OAuth 2.0. But it is otherwise trivial to just split on whitespace, and (*optionally*) decode the string as Base64:

```
from base64 import b64decode

auth = header_string.split(maxsplit=2)  # only interested in the first two parts
token = b64token = None
if len(auth) > 1 and auth.lower() == 'bearer':
    b64token = auth[1]
    try:
        token = b64decode(b64token)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Now `b64token` and `token` are either `None`, or the first non-whitespace portion after `Bearer`, and the base64-decoded version of that string.

A JSON Web Token is actually three Base64-encoded strings joined with `.`, so decoding such a token as a single Base64-encoded value could easily fail. You'd pass the `b64token` string to `PyJWT`.